# Implementing shell in C - pipelined input has correct output but exits loop

Tags: c, shell, pipe, fork, dup2

I am trying to implement a basic shell in  C that handles multiple pipes. It waits for input and execs the commands in a for loop. When it receives EOF, it stops waiting for input and exits.

Right now, my shell outputs the correct output when I input a pipelined command, e.g. `ls | wc | grep ...` but **it stops waiting for input and exits the outer while loop** instead of waiting for the next line of input.

I found that this happens because the fgets in my while loop is returning null (stdin is getting EOF somehow?). I do not get any errors while creating forking, creating a pipe, or execing.

However, if I enter one command at a time without any pipes e.g. `ls`, it successfully prints out the correct output **and** waits for the next line of input, as it should.

My program parses each line of input into a `struct` before trying to execute each command (omitted below). The `struct` is designed such that I can easily pass the parsed arguments into `execvp`, which I will not describe here.

This is a heavily simplified version of my code with most of the error-checking omitted:

```
FILE* input;
char line[MAX_LINE];

input = stdin;
printf("> ");
fflush(stdout);

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input)) {
    int i;
    struct cmdLine;
    /* struct defined elsewhere
    ** commands = # of commands in parsed input
    ** start = index where a command and its args start
    ** args[] = array holding each command/arg
    */

    /* parse input line into cmdLine */
    ...

    /* exec all commands in pipeline except the last */
    for (i = 0; i < cmdLine.commands-1; ++i) {
        int pd[2];
        pipe(pd);

        if (fork() == 0) {
            dup2(pd[1], 1);
            execvp(cmdLine.args[cmdLine.start[i]], &(cmdLine.args[cmdLine.start[i]]));
        } else {
            wait(NULL);
        }

        dup2(pd[0], 0);
        close(pd[1]);
    }    

    /* exec last command */
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execvp(cmdLine.args[cmdLine.start[i]], &(cmdLine.args[cmdLine.start[i]]));
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    if (stdin == input) {
        printf("> ");  /* print shell prompt */
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

I am almost certain I messed up somewhere with my duping, but I've been trying for hours and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Is EOF somehow being sent to stdin so the enclosing `fgets` returns `NULL`?

Comment: "*This is a heavily simplified version of my code with most of the error-checking omitted*" - then why post it at all? See [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried running `strace -f` on your program?

Comment: Because if I posted my entire code then it would be too much for people to want to read? This is simplified enough so that anyone can see my approach without omitting the important lines (fork, pipe, dup2).

Comment: If you don't know where the bug is, how do you know which lines are important and which are not?

Comment: Because I was provided the code handling everything except this portion of the code, which I have been guaranteed is a correct solution. I know that the error lies in this part and it has to do with me calling `dup2`, `fork`, and/or `pipe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `dup2` with 0 (=`stdin`) as the second argument, you are closing the original `stdin` at the end of each iteration of your `for` loop, so you can no longer actually talk to your program via the original stdin.

The problem in your code is that you are trying to hand off connecting all of the pipes together to someone else; that is not going to work. Here's what should work:

- For n programs, you need at least (n-1) pipes.
- Record all of the pipe FDs in arrays: one for the input side of the pipe (that is written to), one for the output side (that is read from).
- For each process you are forking, connect the previous pipe's output (if any) to its `stdin`, and the next pipe's input to its `stdout` (or your main program's `stdout` if you're handling the last process in your chain of pipes).
- Once you've forked everything: in a loop, `poll()` on the output FDs of your pipes, read from any that have activity, and write to the input of the next pipe (your own `stdout` at the end). If you get EOF on one of the pipes, close the next pipe's input (and remove the EOF'd pipe output from your output array). Once all of the FDs are closed, exit your loop.

EDIT: I just thought of another, simpler way that requires less code changes but I haven't *completely* thought it through. :) The problem is that you are destroying your own stdin. If you do all of this (i.e. the whole "process one line of commands) in a forked child, replacing stdin between processes doesn't affect the parent process at all. Still, this would require a lot of buffering in the kernel and so it probably won't scale.

Comment: Thank you so much for actually answering my question - this makes so much more sense. I saw an example on here where the person used only used 2 pipes to iterate through every command, so I thought it would be "cleaner" to do it like so.

Comment: I'm sure there's _some_ way to do it with just two pipes. :) - but actually you *are* creating a new pipe for each process, you're just not remembering all of them. You could totally do this without `poll`, though, if not a lot of data went through the pipes. In that case you could just read everything from each process's output and write it to the input before forking the next. In the real world you'll run into buffer limits, though.

Comment: @itspiuy I actually just thought of a way to probably make it easier: do all of your above work in a forked child (i.e. another fork around the whole part of the code that handles one line of commands). That way the original stdin never goes away in the parent process.

Comment: Just tried the "easy" fix - it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you're right, technically I'm creating a new pipe every time I iterate through the for loop; I meant to say making a giant array of fds, which is a bit "uglier". I realized from reading some other posts earlier that a better way to do this would be to not wait for each process to complete - your suggestion with using `poll` would probably be much more realistic. Fortunately this is a simple practice problem so I don't have to worry about that. Thanks for your help again!